# Saving the best weights and model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras API with Tensorflow back-end to train the DL model. I'm using ModelCheckPoint to monitor the validation accuracy and store only the weights if there is an improvement. In the process, I end up storing the model architecture as JSON and the weights for every improvement. I finally load the best weights and the model architecture to predict on the test data. Here is my code:

```
    filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=validation_generator, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size, verbose=1)
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    model.save('model_complete.h5')
```

I also attempted to save the entire model with "model.save" however, this saved model stores not the best weights but the weights learned at the final epoch which definitely is not the best weights learned in my case. Is there a way to store the architecture and the best weights into a single model file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is already the default behaviour of `ModelCheckpoint` as `save_weights_only=False`. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a9a68bc9deac5d72170ac48c15c41b0defc9753e/keras/callbacks.py#L442) you'll see it already calls `model.save` if you do not specify for it to save the weights only.

Comment: If that solution has worked then it should have been accepted as the answer according to the community good practice :)

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to the community. I just learned to click on the icon. Now I have accepted the answer.